# Where is cmcfg32.lib?

Tags: c++, visual-c++, privileges

I found a source code on MSDN about [how to enable/disable privileges in C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa446619(VS.85).aspx)

According to the source code, the linker must include **cmcfg32.lib**, but it can't be found...

I tried to compile without including that lib, it compiles without any error, but when I launch my program, it crashes with a fatal error.

So please, if you know which SDK contains cmcfg32.lib, let me know ;)

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It looks (to me) like a minor error in the code. Delete the line:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "cmcfg32.lib")
```

Of, if you want the correct library linked automatically, change it to:

```
#pragma comment(lib, "advapi32.lib")
```

Answer (score 4):

This code links for me without trouble, using the 6.0a version of the SDK.  "cmcfg" googles as Connection Manager Configuration, no idea what that is or why it would be needed here.

Just delete the #pragma.